# What does abbreviation “IC:” mean?

Tags: meaning

I have this text here:

> How many daydreams have ever been brought to pass throughout history? (IC: How lamentable!)

It seems like usage of `IC:` is similar to that of `i.e.:` but when I look up IC in Oxford online all I’m getting is:

> Definition of IC in English:
>
> IC
>   ABBREVIATION
>
> 1Integrated circuit.
>   2Internal combustion.
>   ‘the IC engine’

Is it just a misspelling of `i.e.:`? Or something completely different.

Comment: We probably need a bit more context.  From what I see I suspect that "IC" is either the initials of the person commenting (with "How lamentable"), or it stands for "juris consultum", a Latin term for a legal authority.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *Translator's Note* of [the text](https://reader.paperc.com/books/slapping-the-table-in-amazement/923503/translatornote0) contains the following:

[image]

So it's clear that IC means ***interlinear comment***.